# Ubuntu 17.10 remote disk unlock

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption

I have a question about setting up remote unlock with Ubuntu's built-in disk encryption.

I know there are ways to do it with dropbear but I'm not sure.

So here is what I am wanting to do.

Our company manages a number of large crypto currency mines across the US and Canada. We have a specialized mining software that is installed on a server that is placed within the facility.

Now because the software is written in python, we needed a way to allow the client to be able to monitor there mine, but not get our code.

We this was done by giving the client a black box with full encryption, we are the only ones that know the keys. But here is the issue.

If the system reboots, someone currently has to manually enter in the key. We cant have a tech come every time the system gets rebooted either as only management has access to the disk encryption keys on the servers.

What we need done is when the system reboots, it sshs into the keyserver (IP restrictions will be set to only accept incoming connections from certain IP addresses) retrieves the key file that will unlock the drive, unlock the drive, then delete the key file from the facility server.

I know you can do this with dropbear, but every example I have seen you need to issue an ssh command TO the encrypted client from the keyserver. We want it the opposite, so the client requests the key file from the keyserver.

If anyone knows a good tutorial on how to do this, or if someone could point me in the right direction, it would help me and the team quite a bit.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered having a certified third party come in and give you a full once-over from a security policy perspective?  The cardinal rule of IT Security is "Don't give anybody physical access to your machines, they can do almost anything to them with physical access".  Encryption or not.  By giving these 'locked' systems to the clients and then trying to remotely trigger decryption, you're violating rule #1, and will automatically fail all audits, most likely, because physical access alone is enough to 'steal' your 'secret' data.

Comment: And this is a sure-fire way to cause hell for yourself down the road, because you won't be able to really maintain all these 'systems' in a secure manner either.  Especially if the master server gets popped (example: surprise, you just had a bad guy create a botnet *instantly* from your business model because they popped your box with the decryption codes on it, and they embedded malware). (FYI: I am an IT Security professional - this 'setup' you described is one of the "red flags" of a business model that I tend to cringe at for countless security concerns and reasons)

Answer (score 1):

#### With great security comes great responsibility...

What you're trying to do is to eat your cake and keep it too: you want to have a manual key entry, but you want to automate it, so you have three possibilities:

- Ensure the server has remote KVM (Keyboard-Video-Mouse) capabilities (aka Remote Console access): most modern servers have this built-in: *This is still manual work, but it can now be done remotely for a small additional cost **but  rules out a VPS solution**.*
- Deploy commercially available Encryption-At-Rest software that does the key entry for you remotely. *This is fully automated, rule-based and vetted by Security professionals.*
- Change your set-up: allow unsecure boot, and mount `/`, fire off a boot script that connects to a remote server, alerts a remote resource to mount the encrypted partition manually: *FLOSS, and if you insist, you can use  [Dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) but I would stick with the ssh client from your distro of choice that gets automatically updated **when** any security problems would arise in the future...*

Comment: P.S. I would have my security set-up audited by security professionals as I woudn't leave physical access to high-security equipment in a remote site: the equipment should be only physically accessible to the people who have access to the logical key...

Answer (score 0):

I actually have figured this out with a plugin called Mandos. Mandos uses open PGP and ssh tunneling to security grab the key and feeds it into the system. Also, I do understand about security issues with, physical access, however with both full disk encryption plus 2-factor hardware unlock to get on to the admin enabled account, no external facing ssh (it gets closed off right after the unlock) its almost impossible to pop the box, even with physical access. The encryption keys are also not stored on the server, as that would defeat the purpose here. I have done a full audit of this system, even trying to sniff the request it makes to capture it, but nothing was getting past it.

The system also has very very strict IP restrictions on both endpoints, and communicate over a VPN as well, secured by a Meraki device. Sniffing traffic yields just encrypted garbage that would take way to long to crack for anyone to even bother.

We have given one of these boxes to a external security team and even they could not crack it.

The keyserver itself is also PCI-DSS compliant.

The main point is us having to give a system out is our code needs to be run locally on the network of the mine in order for it to function properly. This presented us with the problem of having to give clients the code base(cant compile python to a binary file), as it would not work as a SaaS. And to protect our IP we had to find a system that would work.